# Predictive model with nested variable / repeated measures

Tags: modeling, prediction, model

I would like to build a predictive model for a complicated biological application. To keep it simple, I will compare my situation with soccer. Suppose I want to build a model that predicts how well a soccer team performs. To do that, we need to know what the quality is of the 11 players that are in that team. The problem is, in my training data, I have data on how well a football team has performed, but not how well the football players have performed. So I do not have a single value for each player's quality, but for each player, I do have measurements of several factors that determine the quality of that player. So, lets say, I have measured the football player's speed, height, strength and agility. Also, I have measured strength 3 times with independent experiments. So to summarise, I have

- Football team (for each team I have 1 value)

  - Player 1

    - Speed: 1 value
    - Heigth: 1 value
    - Strength: 3 values, 3 independent measurements
    - Agility: 1 value
  - Player 2

    - Speed: 1 value
    - Heigth: 1 value
    - Strength: 3 values, 3 independent measurements
    - Agility: 1 value
  - Player 3

    - Speed: 1 value
    - Heigth: 1 value
    - Strength: 3 values, 3 independent measurements
    - Agility: 1 value

Can anyone point me into the right direction of what kind of modelling I should pursue? I read that this might be related to mixed models (random and fixed effects), repeated measurements, a latent variable (the quality of the football player) and that bayesian models might be of interest but I have no clue where to start. I am into programming so my question is more what to do rather than how to do that.